# [scala]error: value _2 is not a member of String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

First i start `spark-shell` on windows, and I read a file from local

```
val res0 = sc.textFile("d:\\data\\testdatas\\heightinfo.txt")
```

then i want to get the first and the third column so:

```
res0.flatMap(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x._2,x._0)).collect
```

After this i got the error:

> ```
> value _2 is not a member of String
> ```

Sample data looks like this:

```
张三 男 180
李四 男 189
王五 男 167
赵六 男 170
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You are not using `_1` anywhere in the code that you have provided here. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: sorry,i tried several times ,so i put the mismatched error and steps

Comment: 1) replace `flatMap` with `map` 2) replace `(x._2, x._0)` with `(x(2), x(0))` 3)Head over to https://spark.apache.org and read the basic operations that can be performed with RDDs

Comment: Also, `x._0`, even if it's not needed here, is syntactically incorrect because tuples do not have a 0th index. I'd strongly suggest reading Scala collections and then proceeding to read Spark documentation before you correct these changes.

Comment: ok,thanks, i'll read it before coding

Comment: x is string not a tuple, how you can do x._1 or x._2 or anything such?